# NPM run start, webpack server issue - 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'properties' of undefined'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to run npm with the command `npm run start` but I'm getting an error which seems to be happening when the webpack dev server tries to open:

```
> election@1.0.0 start C:\Users\Aristophanes\election_react\election_react-0.0.1
> webpack-dev-server --open

C:\Users\Aristophanes\election_react\election_react-0.0.1\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\config-yargs.js:89
                                describe: optionsSchema.definitions.output.properties.path.description,
                                                                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'properties' of undefined
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Aristophanes\election_react\election_react-0.0.1\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\config-yargs.js:89:48)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Aristophanes\election_react\election_react-0.0.1\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:84:40)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:741:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:739:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! election@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --open`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the election@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I have run `npm install -g webpack-dev-server` as this has been the solution for similar errors, but the issue persists. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: try running a local version of webpack-dev-server, it uses: "Note: While you can install and run webpack-dev-server globally, we recommend installing it locally. webpack-dev-server will always use a local installation over a global one."

Comment: Hi, I followed the instructions on the webpack-dev-server github regarding installing locally, but I still get the same error when i try 'npm run start'